# Apache ElseIf block entered even though condition is false

Tags: apache

**Back Story:**

I have a copy of all my website files located on two different file servers. I have a two web servers, mimir2 and mimir4, with maps to access the files from either of these file servers. The unique value in the file path to these file servers is either dtg_devel_ah or dtg_devel_nr.

**What I am trying to do:**

I am editing my httpd.conf file to dynamically set, on server start, which file server to use based on the web servers name. I am doing this by using Apaches Define directive to create the variable ***dtg_devel_path*** which will get used in directory paths throughout the rest of the httpd.conf file.

**My Code to accomplish this (Note: There are SetEnv declrations scattered throughout  only for my debugging purposes):**

```
# Define which dtg_devel_xx to use based on server name. This is so that
# the server is accessing its local files instead of across the country
# Default to dtg_devel which will point to which ever server site is active
Define dtg_devel_path dtg_devel

# If running on mimir2 use dtg_devel_nr
# else if run on mimir4 use dtg_devel_ah
<If "env('HOSTNAME') =~ /mimir2/i">
  Define dtg_devel_path dtg_devel_nr
  SetEnv dtg_devel_m2 ${dtg_devel_path}
  SetEnv dtg_devel_hostname_m2 ${HOSTNAME}
</If>
<ElseIf "env('HOSTNAME') =~ /mimir4/i">
  Define dtg_devel_path dtg_devel_ah
  SetEnv dtg_devel_m4 ${dtg_devel_path}
  SetEnv dtg_devel_hostname_m4 ${HOSTNAME}
</ElseIf>

SetEnv dtg_devel_final_set_path ${dtg_devel_path}
SetEnv dtg_devel_hostname ${HOSTNAME}
```

**When I run this the values getting set are:**

[image]

**My Problem:**

The value of ***dtg_devel_path*** should be ***dtg_devel_nr***. I am running this on server ***mimir2*** which you can see is confirmed from the above picture. The if part of the if/elseif statement is returning true (HOSTNAME equals mimir2) and in turn setting ***dtg_devel_path***, ***dtg_devel_hostname_m2***, and ***dtg_devel_m2***. Strangely though somehow ***dtg_devel_path*** then gets changed to the value ***dtg_devel_ah*** even though the elseif block never gets entered. This is confirmed by the value of the ***dtg_devel_final_set_path*** variable and the lack of values for ***dtg_devel_m4*** and ***dtg_devel_hostname_m4***. This code block is the only location that the string ***dtg_devel_ah*** appears so this has to be where it is getting set.

Does anyone see the mistake that I have in my code? Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! If any additional information is needed please let me know.

Comment: I suspect a problem with `Define` which is documented as not impacted by surrounding scope. Examples shows usage of `Define` in `IfDefine` blocks but not in simple `If` blocks. Have you tried using only `SetEnv` instead?

Comment: 2nd comment because you can only edit comments for so long.

I was going to try that but I cannot figure out how to access the variable later in the .conf file after its created using SetEnv. I don't know if I'm suddenly blind but I've been searching for hours and I can't find any documentation. After running a SetEnv dtg_devel_path dtg_devel_nr I've tried accessing it by doing ${dtg_devel_path}, %{dtg_devel_path}, and several other syntax's but none are working for me.

Comment: You have some ways of using it on several modules, in mod_rewrite you have the `%{ENV:variable}` syntax in `rewriteCond`for example. mod_headers can also be altered based on envorinoments variables, but there is no global rule AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to solve this completely through Apache so I ended up going a slightly different path. My web server is running on a RHEL 6.4 machine fyi.

I basically pulled the if/else function that I had in the http.conf file and put it into three places; `/etc/profile.d/dtg_deve_path.<sh,csh>` and `/etc/init.d/httpd`. These files check the host name and create a DTG_DEVEL_PATH environment variable based on that value. I then access that value in httpd.conf with a `Define dtg_devel_path ${DTG_DEVEL_PATH}` which then lets me accomplish what I was trying to do, use `${dtg_devel_path}` through the rest of the httpd.conf file to dynamically specify which file server to use.